# ValueError: Protocol message OrderedJob has no "template" field

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-dataproc, google-workflows

I'm writing a Google Cloud Function that invokes a Dataproc Workflow defined in a YAML file on cloud storage.

When testing the invocation, the function crashes immediately with the following stack trace:

```
"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/proto/message.py", line 570, in __init__
    pb_value = marshal.to_proto(pb_type, value)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/proto/marshal/marshal.py", line 217, in to_proto
    pb_value = rule.to_proto(value)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/proto/marshal/rules/message.py", line 36, in to_proto
    return self._descriptor(**value)
ValueError: Protocol message OrderedJob has no "template" field."
```

When I looked at the documentation for OrderedJob, there's no field (mandatory or otherwise called 'template'. Googling the exact error yields 0 results so I am a bit stuck. Any advice would be welcome, since this is my first time using workflows and I'm not sure where to even start.

Answer (score 0):

On this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.dataproc.v1#orderedjob) I see that the step_id field is the only required in the list. And looking at the stacktrace this is possibly a python or dataproc version issue. You can visit the [document](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/dataproc/latest) here for Python/API compatibility and steps to install dataproc.